# What does Pandas dataframe copy do?

Tags: pandas, virtual-memory

My question is basically does dataframe.copy() use copy-on-write?

I am guessing (and I am probably wrong) that when someone calls dataframe.copy(), it is calling malloc somewhere to allocate virtual memory for the new dataframe. I believe malloc doesn't initialize the virtual memory, so it is copy-on-write and no physical data movement happens. This implies there is no real copy of the dataframe when copy() is called.

However, calling dataframe.copy() does take time and increase my memory footprint. So it looks like it is indeed making a physical copy of the data. Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: it depends on the `deep` argument (default is `True`), see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Comment: The copy is optimistic, a new DataFrame is returned on calling copy().

Comment: @Stef the doc does not quite answer my question. My question is if deep copy is used, when does actual copy happen? Is it at the time copy is called or is it at the time data are written to it?

Comment: Oh sorry, is mis-read your question.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. When you do `df1 = df.copy()`, the system clones the data and all headers (probably with `malloc`), creates a new object with that new data in memory and call it `df1`. So yes, it does increase the memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

With default `deep=True` it's definitely allocating new memory, but it's also copying the data there right away. So memory footprint will increase immediately. It doesn't do copy-on-write for either `.copy(deep=True)` or `.copy(deep=False)`. When you do `deep=False` both DataFrames will be using same data, when you do `deep=True` data is copied. Malloc not initializing new memory only would be relevant here if you allocated memory and never put anything there.

Columns are just Series objects backed by numpy ndarrays. And they don't do copy-on-write (see [NumPy Array Copy-On-Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896030/numpy-array-copy-on-write)).